# EM::WebSocket.run as well as INotify file-watching

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

This is the code I currently have:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'em-websocket'
$cs = []
EM.run do
    EM::WebSocket.run(:host => "::", :port => 8085) do |ws|
        ws.onopen do |handshake|
            $cs << ws
        end
        ws.onclose do
            $cs.delete ws
        end
    end
end
```

I would like to watch a file with `rb-inotify` and send a message to all connected clients (`$cs.each {|c| c.send "File changed"}`) when a file changes. The problem is, I do not understand EventMachine, and I can't seem to find a good tutorial.

So if anyone could explain to me where to put the `rb-inotify`-related code, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course! As soon as I post the question, I figure it out!

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'em-websocket'
$cs = []
module Handler
    def file_modified
        $cs.each {|c| c.send "File was modified!" }
    end
end
EM.run do
    EM.watch_file("/tmp/foo", Handler)
    EM::WebSocket.run(:host => "::", :port => 8085) do |ws|
        ws.onopen do |handshake|
            $cs << ws
        end
        ws.onclose do
            $cs.delete ws
        end
    end
end
```